# Problem :Debuging in Visual C++ 2008 for opencv C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using openCV 2.1 on visual c++ 2008, I made a simple program and when I tried to debug it in an **step into** manner, since I want to know the source of the function but cvLoadImage, Its gives an error "the source is not found for this function " and it automatically goes to the next statement. This happens all the time for each line of the program.
I am new to this kind of setting to be specified for the debug to go into the libraries and work properly. can any one please help me on this.

**the code I used is**

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
     IplImage *img = cvLoadImage("funny-pictures-cat-goes-pew.jpg");
     cvNamedWindow("Image:",1);
     cvShowImage("Image:",img);

     cvWaitKey();
     cvDestroyWindow("Image:");
     cvReleaseImage(&img);

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please use `{}` to format the code present on the editor window.

Comment: Stepping into opencv source code requires downloading the source code, building the library from it using Debug configuration settings and linking it to your program.  Did you do this?

Answer (score 0):

I saw this on the OpenCV homepage. Did you include the headers and the picture? You might want to revise and check your code to see if it matches with the one on the bottom of http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VisualC%2B%2B_VS2010.

Comment: I have recctified the rpoblem, i tried with the tutrial in http://nashruddin.com/OpenCV_2_0_Installation_on_Windows_XP_and_Visual_Studio_2008